# How to check for repeated yield from a Python generator function?

Tags: python, generator, permutation, python-itertools

I'm trying to generate a list of ways to organize a list containing x number of element a and z number of element b. `itertools.permutations()` returns every possible way of organizing that list, which would be great, but it gives multiple versions of functionally the same permutation. this is because it tries to order every item in the list rather than ordering every unique item. ex. it sees `['item a' //first instance of item a//, 'item b', 'item a' //second instance of item a//]` as different from `['item a' //second instance of item a//, 'item b', 'item a'//first instance of item a//]` because the first and second instances of 'item a' are distinct, even though both lists are really just `['item a', 'item b', 'item a']`.

I solved this problem with this code:

```
def permutations():
            list_of_yielded_permutations = []
            for permutation in itertools.permutations(list_i_want_to_find_permutations_of, r=len(list_i_want_to_find_permutations_of)):
                if permutation not in list_of_yielded_permutations:
                    list_of_yielded_permutations.append(permutation)
                    yield permutation
```

this returns unique permutations the way I want it to, but it isn't ideal for one major reason. when I call the function for a long list (ex. 16 total entries, 7 `'item a'`, 9 `'item b'`), it takes an insanely long time to complete. it's currently taking up 40% of my cpu and has been running for three and a half hours without completing. I'm sure there's got to be a more performance-efficient way to go about this, but I have no idea what it could be.

Edit: I've looked into `itertools.combinations()` and it doesn't give me the results that I want in my actual use case. I just need to know how to do what I'm already doing but more efficiently.

Comment: You can use combinations: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations

Comment: Would it be useful to eliminate the duplicate values in the input list, e.g. with `set` before finding the permutations?

Comment: @Caridorc I've looked into it and combinations does not give me the results that I want in my actual use case.

Comment: In your case with 7*a and 9*b, you can restate the problem as "choose 7 indexes (don't care which order) such that the target permutation will contain 'a' at those positions". There are "only" 16-choose-7 = 11440 of them and you can get them with `itertools.combinations()`. You can generalise this - if there are N distinct values in your source list, loop through N-1 of them to choose the combinations of indexes they will occupy. (A bit trickier than it sounds tbf: when you synthesise the results into permutations, you need to think of the indexes in terms of the *remaining empty* slots)

Comment: Would you literally only have x of 'item a' and y of 'item b' though, and never an 'item c'? That case is more straightforward than the generalised one.

Comment: Why are you asking about checking (and ignoring) repeated yields? That prevents alternatives that don't have repeated yields in the first place from being valid answers to the question.

Comment: Why doesn't the `unique_everseen` itertools recipe work for you? I.e., why are you using a list instead of a set? Are your actual values not strings but something unhashable?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there will only be 'item a' and 'item b' and never an 'item c', we can restate the problem as "choose the **indexes** that will be occupied by 'item a' in the target permutations".

For a given permutation, we don't care about the order of those indexes (by the stipulation that all 'items a' are identical), so this reduces to a problem of combinations rather than permutations, eliminating the iteration over all the identical permutations.

```
import itertools as it

def perms(num_a, num_b):
  res = []
  # A bit more efficient if we choose the indexes of the "minority" element
  if num_a < num_b:
    elem_sm, elem_lg = 'a', 'b'
    num_sm = num_a
  else:
    elem_sm, elem_lg = 'b', 'a'
    num_sm = num_b
  base_perm = [elem_lg] * (num_a + num_b)
  
  for c in it.combinations(range(num_a + num_b), num_sm):
    # c is the tuple of indexes that will be occupied by
    # the "minority" element
    perm = base_perm[:]
    for i in c:
      perm[i] = elem_sm
    res.append(perm)

  return res

x = perms(num_a=7, num_b=9)
print(len(x))
print(x[0])  # First permutation
print("---")
print(x[-1])  # Last permutation
```

Results:

```
11440
['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b']
---
['b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
```

Answer (score 0):

`itertools.permutations` itself is the main bottleneck in your code for high `a` and `b`, because it has time complexity O(n!) where `n = a + b`.

In your present solution, the list lookup in each loop adds some further complexity, making it O(nn!). This part at least can be replaced with a set lookup, which is [O(1) for the average case](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

```
def permutations(a, b):
     items = "a" * a + "b" * b
     seen = set()
     for permutation in itertools.permutations(items):
         if permutation not in seen:
              seen.add(permutation)
              yield permutation
```

For `a = 3, b = 4` this is about 3 times faster than using a list on my machine but remains very slow for higher `n`. To get faster you have to avoid using permutations in the first place.

One more efficient solution (O(n2^n) I think), since there are two types of item, is to treat it as a binary counting exercise, yielding only those strings that have the right number of item a and item b.

```
def permutations_str(a, b):
    r = "a" * a + "b" * b
    stop = "b" * b + "a" * a
    yield r
    while r != stop:
        i = r.index("b")
        r = i * "b" + "a" + r[i+1:]  # like incrementing a binary number written from right to left
        if r.count("a") == a:
            yield r
```

Another solution (yielding 0s and 1s instead of a and b) has similar complexity but is faster because it simply counts in integers:

```
def permutations_bin(zeros, ones):  # yields integers
    start = 2 ** ones - 1
    end = start * (2 ** zeros) 
    yield start
    for number in range(start + 1, end):
        if bin(number).count("1") == ones:
            yield number
    yield end

def permutations_bin_as_string(zeros, ones): # converts the integers to binary strings
    length = zeros + ones
    for n in permutations_bin(zeros, ones):
        yield format(n, f"0{length}b")
```

In Python 3.10 you can make this faster still using [`int.bit_count()`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_count) instead of `bin(number).count("1")`.